# JavaScript CSS how to add and remove multiple CSS classes to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, append

How can assign multiple css classes to an html element through javascript without using any libraries?

Comment: I see by the answers there is some confusion here.  Do you want to be able to apply a constant set of multiple classes to an element, or do you want to be able to add more classes to an element that it originally has?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try doing this...

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

Got this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)...

Comment: You only need to separate each class name with a space: object.className = `"class1 class2 class3 "`

Answer (score 166):

Here's a simpler method to add multiple classes via `classList` (supported by all modern browsers, as noted in other answers here):

`div.classList.add('foo', 'bar');   // add multiple classes`

From:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples

If you have an array of class names to add to an element, you can use the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to pass them all into `classList.add()` via this one-liner:

```
let classesToAdd = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];
div.classList.add(...classesToAdd);
```

Note that not all browsers support ES6 natively yet, so as with any other ES6 answer you'll probably want to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), or just stick with ES5 and use a solution like @LayZee's above.

Answer (score 45):

This works:

```
myElement.className = 'foo bar baz';
```

Comment: thats not good because you lose the classes that are already there if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 36):

There are at least a few different ways:

```
var buttonTop = document.getElementById("buttonTop");

buttonTop.className = "myElement myButton myStyle";

buttonTop.className = "myElement";

buttonTop.className += " myButton myStyle";

buttonTop.classList.add("myElement");

buttonTop.classList.add("myButton", "myStyle");

buttonTop.setAttribute("class", "myElement");

buttonTop.setAttribute("class", buttonTop.getAttribute("class") + " myButton myStyle");

buttonTop.classList.remove("myElement", "myButton", "myStyle");
```

Comment: Offering examples is good, but it would be helpful if you could explain which use cases call for which of those ways. Without that we're sort of just lost in the outback.

Answer (score 15):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')

el[0].classList.add('newclass');

el[0].classList.remove('newclass');
```

To find whether the class exists or not, use:

```
el[0].classList.contains('newclass'); // this will return true or false
```

Browser support IE8+

Answer (score 11):

You can add and remove multiple classes in same way with different in-built methods:

```
const myElem = document.getElementById('element-id');
//add multiple classes
myElem.classList.add('class-one', 'class-two', 'class-three');
//remove multiple classes
myElem.classList.remove('class-one', 'class-two', 'class-three');
```

Answer (score 10):

2 great ways to **ADD**:

*But the first way is more cleaner, since for the second you have to add a space at the beginning*. *This is to avoid the class name from joining with the previous class.*

```
element.classList.add("d-flex", "align-items-center");
element.className += " d-flex align-items-center";
```

Then to **REMOVE** use the cleaner way, by use of classList

```
element.classList.remove("d-grid", "bg-danger");
```

Answer (score 9):

Since I could not find this answer nowhere:

ES6 way (Modern Browsers)

```
el.classList.add("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Answer (score 8):

guaranteed to work on new browsers. the old className way may not, since it's deprecated.

```
<element class="oneclass" />

element.setAttribute('class', element.getAttribute('class') + ' another');
alert(element.getAttribute('class')); // oneclass another
```

Answer (score 3):

just use this

```
element.getAttributeNode("class").value += " antherClass";
```

take care about Space to avoid mix old class with new class

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
document.getElementById("myEle").className = "class1 class2";
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: I think this might remove the other classes on the element, if there are any

Answer (score 2):

the `Element.className += " MyClass";` **is not recommended approach** because it will always add these classes whether they were exit or not.

in my case, I was uploading an image file and adding classes to it, now with this each time you upload an image it will add these class whether they exist or not,

**the recommended way is** `Element.classList.add("class1" , "class2" , "class3");`
this way will not add extra classes if they already there.

Answer (score 2):

Css classes can be added or removed from DOM elements using the classList property that contains the add or remove functions e.g

**Add Css Classes**

```
//you can add multiple classes

 element.classList.add("a", "b", "c");
```

**Remove Css Classes**

```
//you can remove multiple classes

  element.classList.remove("a", "b", "c");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function addClass(element, value) {
  if(!element.className) {
    element.className = value;
  } else {
    newClassName = element.className;
    newClassName+= " ";
    newClassName+= value;
    element.className = newClassName;
  }
}
```

Similar logic could be used to make a removeClass function.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

This allows for a (vanilla) JavaScript function like this:

```
var addClasses;

addClasses = function (selector, classArray) {
    'use strict';

    var className, element, elements, i, j, lengthI, lengthJ;

    elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    // Loop through the elements
    for (i = 0, lengthI = elements.length; i < lengthI; i += 1) {
        element = elements[i];

        // Loop through the array of classes to add one class at a time
        for (j = 0, lengthJ = classArray.length; j < lengthJ; j += 1) {
            className = classArray[j];

            element.classList.add(className);
        }
    }
};
```

Modern browsers (not IE) support passing multiple arguments to the `classList::add` function, which would remove the need for the nested loop, simplifying the function a bit:

```
var addClasses;

addClasses = function (selector, classArray) {
    'use strict';

    var classList, className, element, elements, i, j, lengthI, lengthJ;

    elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    // Loop through the elements
    for (i = 0, lengthI = elements.length; i < lengthI; i += 1) {
        element = elements[i];
        classList = element.classList;

        // Pass the array of classes as multiple arguments to classList::add
        classList.add.apply(classList, classArray);
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
addClasses('.button', ['large', 'primary']);
```

**Functional version**

```
var addClassesToElement, addClassesToSelection;

addClassesToElement = function (element, classArray) {
    'use strict';

    classArray.forEach(function (className) {
       element.classList.add(className);
    });
};

addClassesToSelection = function (selector, classArray) {
    'use strict';

    // Use Array::forEach on NodeList to iterate over results.
    // Okay, since we’re not trying to modify the NodeList.
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (element) {
        addClassesToElement(element, classArray)
    });
};

// Usage
addClassesToSelection('.button', ['button', 'button--primary', 'button--large'])
```

The `classList::add` function will prevent multiple instances of the same CSS class as opposed to some of the previous answers.

Resources on the classList API:

- [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/classlist)
- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-classlist-api)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you learn:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, htm, C, E, addClassName, removeClassName; // for use onload elsewhere
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
addClassName = function(element, className){
  var rx = new RegExp('^(.+\s)*'+className+'(\s.+)*$');
  if(!element.className.match(rx)){
    element.className += ' '+className;
  }
  return element.className;
}
removeClassName = function(element, className){
  element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp('\s?'+className), '');
  return element.className;
}
var out = E('output'), mn = doc.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
out.innerHTML = addClassName(mn, 'wow');
out.innerHTML = addClassName(mn, 'cool');
out.innerHTML = addClassName(mn, 'it works');
out.innerHTML = removeClassName(mn, 'wow');
out.innerHTML = removeClassName(mn, 'main');

}); // close load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  addClass(element, className1, className2){
    element.classList.add(className1, className2);
  }
  removeClass(element, className1, className2) {
    element.classList.remove(className1, className2);
  }

removeClass(myElement, 'myClass1', 'myClass2');
addClass(myElement, 'myClass1', 'myClass2');
```

Answer (score 0):

ClassList add

```js
var dynamic=document.getElementById("dynamic");
dynamic.classList.add("red");
dynamic.classList.add("size");
dynamic.classList.add("bold");
```

```css
.red{
color:red;
}
.size{
font-size:40px;
}
.bold{
font-weight:800;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic">dynamic css</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using classname property
you can add multiple classes by passing all the classes as a string separated by space. This is more convenient way to do so

```
newLi.className= "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `String.prototype.split()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
"btn btn-sm btn-light my-2".split(" ").forEach(className => locationButton.classList.add(className));
```