# apply a compound css rule in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably just an easy question but how do i apply a css rule to a compound section instead of just to a specific id for example i currently have:

```
var pillpic = document.getElementById('pill');
pillpic.style.left="300px";
pillpic.style.top="160px";
```

How do i change this to instead be a style applied to a compound rule? like for example this:

```
#wrapper #photoslider #appframe #clock img {}
```

which if i was doing it in a stylesheet i could use

Comment: You could just use document.getElementById('clock').getElementsByTagName('IMG')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest (in up-to-date browsers):

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper #photoslider #appframe #clock img');
[].forEach.call(images, function(a){
    a.style.top = 160px;
    a.style.left = 300px;
});
```

Or, rather than adjusting the `style` on each iteration, use CSS and add a class:

```
.classNameOfRelevantImages {
    top: 160px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

And the JavaScript to add that class:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper #photoslider #appframe #clock img');
[].forEach.call(images, function(a){
    a.classList.add('classNameOfRelevantImages');
}
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) <sup>([compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t14))</sup>.
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: You could just use pill.getElementsByTagName('IMG')

Comment: I could, but that doesn't represent the full selector, does it? And if the styles should only be applied *if* the entirety of those identified ancestors are present, your version wouldn't actually be correct.

Comment: first example makes a lot of sense and it is easy to understand thank you

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
var pillpic = document.getElementById('pill');
pillpic.className = pillpic.className + "yourclass";
```

or check this [JavaScript CSS how to add and remove multiple CSS classes to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988514/javascript-css-how-to-add-and-remove-multiple-css-classes-to-an-element)

Comment: Then change the looks via css (#pill.yourClass{left:...})?